# VSS: Move file from one folder to another?

Tags: version-control, file, visual-sourcesafe

Is there a way in Visual SourceSafe to move a file from one directory to another while retaining its history?

---

**Edit**
I actually found a round about way to do this. First I drag the file I want to move to the directory I want to move it to, this creates a "Link" to the file there and then I "permanently destroy" the file in its original location.

Does this actually do what I thing it does?

Comment: What is it that you think it does?

Comment: "Move file from one folder to another"

Answer (score 3):

For those of you still suffering SourceSafe, in the File menu, click Move.

Comment: But one must have the permission to delete the file from the original location.

Comment: The suffering must go on, until morale improves! Thanks for this, it was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is no.  VSS sees moving a repository as "branching" the code.  So the new repository location is seen as a new version of the code you are moving.  That's why the history is saved.  Best thing to do is to leave the mis-named repository in place and branch the code under a new name.